# How to get the CPU Usage in C?

Tags: c, cpu

I want to get the overall total CPU usage for an application in C, the total CPU usage like we get in the TaskManager... 
I want to know ... for windows and linux :: current Total CPU utilization by all processes ..... as we see in the task manager.

Comment: What operating system? Do you want to know the answer for your process or for some other process?

Comment: well, in Windows (7 to be precise)... I want to know ... current Total CPU utilization by all processes ..... as we see in the task manager ....

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is platform-specific:

- In Windows, you can use the [`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
- In Linux, you can actually just use `clock()`.

These can be used to measure the amount of CPU time taken between two time intervals.

**EDIT :**

To get the CPU consumption (as a percentage), you will need to divide the total CPU time by the # of logical cores that the OS sees, and then divided by the total wall-clock time:

```
% CPU usage = (CPU time) / (# of cores) / (wall time)
```

Getting the # of logical cores is also platform-specific:

- Windows: [`GetSystemInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Linux: `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)`

Comment: what u suggest is :: Retrieves timing information for the specified process. .... but i need to get the total CPU usage (percentage) - like we see in the task manager..... can you help ??

Comment: Those can be used to give you the CPU time used. To get the % CPU usage, you will need to divide it by the # of logical cores that the OS sees.

Comment: To get get the CPU % usage you would need ( CPU time / # of cores */ wall-clock time elapsed* ), but otherwise correct.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the wall-clock part as well! Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 3):

Under POSIX, you want getrusage(2)'s ru_utime field. Use RUSAGE_SELF for just the calling process, and RUSAGE_CHILDEN for all terminated and wait(2)ed-upon children. Linux also supports RUSAGE_THREAD for just the calling thread. Use ru_stime if you want the system time, which can be summed with ru_utime for total time actively running (not wall time).

Answer (score 1):

It is usually operating system specific.

You could use the [clock](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/CPU-Time.html) function, returning a `clock_t` (some integer type, like perhaps `long`). On Linux systems it measures the CPU time in microseconds.

Comment: `clock_t` is an *arithmetic* type, so it could also be `double` or `float`.