# cpu utilization in C

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to get %CPU utilization with C. I have seen this solution : [How to get the CPU Usage in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501706/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

Hence I had tried with the helps provided there :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NANO2SEC 1000000000

struct timespec gettimenow;
double getWtime;
double getCtick;
int ncore;
double cpu_util;

double get_wall_time () {
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&gettimenow)){
        //error handle
        return 0;
    }
    return ( (double)gettimenow.tv_sec + ( (double)gettimenow.tv_nsec / NANO2SEC ) );
}


double get_cpu_time () {
    return ( (double)clock() / sysconf (_SC_CLK_TCK));
}

int core_logical () {
    return (sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN));
}

void main() {
    getWtime = get_wall_time ();
    printf("\nWall time : %f \n", getWtime);

    getCtick = get_cpu_time ();
    printf("\nCPU time : %f \n", getCtick);

    ncore = core_logical ();
    printf("\nNo of cores : %d \n", ncore);

    cpu_util = (getCtick/ncore/getWtime);
    printf("\nCPU Utilization : %f %% \n", cpu_util);
}
```

The o/p :

Wall time : 1439132892.054816

CPU time : 17.280000

No of cores : 2

CPU Utilization : 0.000000 %

But with top command I found that cpu utilization is not at all 0% it is more that that. ie. 6.2 %
I want to know % of CPU utilized at current time.

Comment: @Anton.P same result

Comment: What do you want to get the cpu usage for? The system? A process?

Comment: @thatotherguy total cpu utilization of a system in %

Answer (score 3):

What your program is doing doesn't make any sense.

You're dividing `clock()`, which returns the amount of CPU time used by the current process, by the number of seconds since 1970. Of course this doesn't give you a meaningful answer!

If you want to get the current CPU usage of the system, you'll need to use the data provided by `/proc/uptime`. When read, this file returns two numbers, representing the number of seconds the system has been running, and the number of seconds it's been idle. So, to find the current CPU usage:

1. Open and read the file and save the two numbers you get. Let's call them `uptime1` and `idle1`. Close it.
2. Wait for one second.
3. Open and read the file again; save the numbers as `uptime2` and `idle2`.
4. CPU usage over that second was `100 - 100 * (idle2 - idle1) / (uptime2 - uptime1)` percent.

Comment: that proc uptime is a system provided value already calculated. I want to calculate via c. not want to do system call

Comment: @Zim `top` calculates all its numbers based on information from `/proc`.

Comment: **There is nothing shameful about using `/proc`.** It's just as much a part of the kernel interface as any system call, and it's the only place that a lot of information is available at all.

Comment: @thatotherguy and proc must get info from other source hence I want the direct measurement not via shell

Comment: @Zim No, it does not. Reading from the pseudofiles in `/proc` fetches information directly from the kernel.

Comment: then I would go for kernel call

Comment: @Zim Here's how [/proc/uptime is calculated](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/uptime.c#L10).

Comment: @Zim That's what reading from `/proc` is. `read()` is a system call too, after all!

Comment: I got the uptime but not cpu utilization @thatotherguy

Comment: @Zim So get the idle time and calculate it.

Comment: @Zim I explain how to get CPU utilization in my answer. Please read it. :)

Comment: There is a recent explanation on [Gathering CPU utilization from /proc/stat](https://www.idnt.net/en-GB/kb/941772) that includes an example in bash.