# Where can I find the normalized cpu load in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've tried with /proc/loadavg but I don't want the avg. Is there any way to do the math like get the realtime use of all of my cores and then divide it by the full capacity of my cpu?

here is a good explanation of what I need https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler/28696

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the CPU Usage in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501706/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the normalized cpu load is available any where, but you can do something like

normalized cpuload = (cpu load measured/normalization factor) * weight

normalized cpuload would actually give you a value, if it is greater than weight is considered overloaded. normalization factor here would be 1.